# SharePoint 2010 Calendar Pending Event in color

Tags: 2010

Can any one of you please provide the solution to get pending events in color for SharePoint 2010 calendar.

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint already has a view called Current Events. I would see potential at least 2 quick solutions:

1. Rely on Calendar Overlays - basically go for "Calendars in View" (on
   the left panel) and simply target the "Current Events" view, on the
   exact same list, on the same site. Choose a color and you're done.
2. Use the HTML Color Calculated column for more advanced scenarios, which would involve creating calculated columns generating HTML and using that as part of the View columns to show in the Week header/Day header, etc. See here a complete example http://sarahlhaase.wordpress.com/2012/06/06/using-calculated-columns-to-add-color-coding-to-your-sharepoint-lists/ - it works the same for SharePoint 2007 and 2010